# resizing google maps v2 on android

Tags: android, android-animation, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to create an animation that stretches the MapFragment as the user pulls down on the screen. The physics is all there, as it was working when I was using Google Maps v1. However, after the upgrade, it seems as though the re-drawing of the new map isn't very fast. This is how I am resizing the MapFragment.

```
    mHeaderView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
    mHeaderView.requestLayout();
```

I've tried invalidate() and forceLayout() to no avail.

The MapFragment ends up turning black in the expanded area, until about 0.5 seconds later when the fragment redraws itself. It makes it look extremely weird. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. You may read more about it (and maybe find workaround) here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

and here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639